# How to install movie.el (movie browser for Emacs)?

Tags: package

I found out there is movies browser for Emacs.
But there is no instruction of how to get it works.

https://github.com/larsmagne/movie.el

Comment: This will likely be closed as unclear or too broad. You don't say what you tried, what symptoms you expected, and what symptoms you saw instead.

Comment: You might want to contact the author of that library, and ask for some doc, if there is none.

Comment: Download them, put them in your `load-path` and `require` them. See https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath and https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RequiredFeature

Comment: Yes you should contact the author since it doesn't seem trivial. A comment on the author's website: "This seems really cool, but some install & instructions for the dummies among us would be helpful. Installing the “standard” way — i.e. (require 'movie) just results in “Required feature 'movie' was not provided” — even though one can subsequently invoke M-x RET movie-browse, for instance. Also, thumbnails aren't being generated, and I'm not exactly sure where that Perl code needs to go. "